# A deleted answer

Tags: support, specific-question

12 days ago I asked a question: [$\text{Hom}(\mathbb{F}_p G, M)$ and $H^1(G,M)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231676/hom-mathbbf-p-g-m-and-h1g-m)

I got an answer quickly. I'm looking for it now, but the answer was deleted.
I don't know why it was deleted, but I'm afraid I might have offended the author of the answer by not accepting.

I left a comment that I will accept the answer once I can verify it's correct (I have to learn some material in order to do that). Today I have the time to do that, but the answer is no longer there.

I'm a bit at loss here. Is there a way to recover the deleted answer or notify the poster of the answer that I'm thankful and interested in seeing the answer again?

Comment: I just added a comment to another question by this user, mentioning the present page.

Comment: It's also conceivable that the person who posted the Answer found a gap or mistake and wanted to remove it simply to avoid misleading anyone.

Comment: The question may be moot, as someone else has posted an answer, which user3533 has accepted.

Comment: [Are there some possibilities for users below 10k to see deleted posts of other users?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13328)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users with 10000 reputation can [see deleted posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools). If you do not fall into that category, [the author of the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/22517/ralph) or [a moderator](https://math.stackexchange.com/about) can undelete the post. In case the post is erroneous, a moderator may review the post or talk to the author before taking such action.