# Are there some possibilities for users below 10k to see deleted posts of other users?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Users that have at least 10k reputation [can view deleted questions and answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). IIRC every user can see their own deleted recent questions on their profile page. (For more details, see: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948))

Are there any tricks that users with reputation below 10k can use to see deleted posts?

Comment: Originally I have posted this in comments to [another question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13327/access-and-see-deleted-questions). But I did not read that question carefully enough - the OP was asking about viewing their own questions. I suppose the information here might be useful for some users, but it was off-topic there. That's why I have moved it to a new question.

Comment: The easiest way is just to get 10k points.

Comment: If you know the URL of the deleted question and date before it was deleted, then try the [Web Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20220921031258/https://math.stackexchange.com/). Does it work?

Comment: @TymaGaidash It is a bit unclear to me what you meant by the question: "Does it work?" I left a [few comments in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/conversation/looking-for-deleted-posts-in-the-wayback-machine) - including an example of question that can be found in the Wayback Machine. Feel free to ping me there, if some further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 5):

If you remember some parts of the text of the question (title, usernames of user who participated there). You can try Google. If you are lucky, you can find that it is still in Google cache, or that one of the [many sites that copy content from SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers) contains the question.

- For example, the question [Sine after sine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149535/sine-after-sine) is deleted here at MSE. If I google for the title, I can find some version of this question in the [search results](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22sine+after+sine%22). (At techques, one of the scraper sites.)
- The question [how many numbers of single digit multiplication is performed in Karatsuba Algorithm To multiply two 6 digit numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730649/how-many-numbers-of-single-digit-multiplication-is-performed-in-karatsuba-algori) has been deleted recently. If you try to search for the [title in Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22how%20many%20numbers%20of%20single%20digit%20multiplication%20is%20performed%20in%20Karatsuba%20Algorithm%20To%20multiply%20two%206%20digit%20numbers%22), you will find the text of the questions in Google cache. (This works at the moment, I do not know how long will this last.)

Basically the same holds for answer - if it was deleted recently enough, it might still be in Google cache. And some scraper site might have copied the answer.

Also if the deletion was recent enough the post might still be in the data contained in [data explorer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info). But it might be tricky to find it there. See, for example, some suggestions given in [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10348/how-to-determine-which-question-answer-was-deleted/10349#10349).

If you know the link to the question (for example from your browser history) you can get link to the cached version of the question in the way described here: [How to modify a URL to get a Google cached version of page?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15633/how-to-modify-a-url-to-get-a-google-cached-version-of-page) at webapps.SE.

If you have the link, you can also check whether some version of the post was not saved in [Wayback Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Archive).

Comment: Technically speaking, you could also get elected moderator.

Comment: Or ask as a favor a 10K user to send you a screenshot/copy.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Does a 10K+ user really allowed to do that?

Comment: @achillehui: Many people do things they are not supposed to be doing.

Comment: @achillehui They are not bound by moderator agreement, and nothing in the SE terms of service prohibits taking and sharing screenshots of deleted posts. Anyone can post a collection of deleted MSE posts  on their website if they wish. For StackOverflow [this already exists](http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/) (it relies on comparing past data dumps to present site, which scales better than taking screenshots).

Answer (score 3):

When you flag a question, you can still see the number of given answers, indicated by the number next to the title in your flagging history, even if it's deleted:

[image]