# How to search a question/answer in MSE

Tags: discussion, support, search

I have missed a question asked in MSE yesterday. I tried searching it but in vain.
Can someone help me in searching $(1+\frac{1}{x})\text{arcTan} x >1$ here in MSE?

Comment: We have meta.math.SE for this sort of question.

Comment: For an experienced user, you should look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching) in the “Dates” section

Comment: Have you tried Approach Zero? I use that one a lot.

Comment: Please tell this approach zero.

Comment: https://approach0.xyz/search/

Comment: It is also easier to find something with the site search engine, if you restrict the search to a specific tag. When/if (as is the case here), a formula is the key, then Approach0 is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you're looking for this question: [Prove that $(1+\frac{1}{x})\arctan(x) > 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4608984). The question was posted 2022-12-31 14:55:50Z and deleted by the OP 16:21:36Z.

Since the question was deleted, the options how to find it are rather limited. It was deleted by the OP, so it won't be shown in the [10k-tools](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/10k-tools/info). (See also: [Why are self-deleted posts not shown in the 10k Tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292531))

Since you mentioned that the question was rather recent, I tried to search for [arctan frac](https://www.google.com/search?q=arctan+frac+site:math.stackexchange.com&tbs=qdr:d) in Google, with the restriction to this site and to past 24 hours.

The [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) database has already been updated since the deletion. (I will remind that it is only updated once a week.) So one could find this question among the [deleted questions tagged calculus](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/845253/deleted-questions-between-two-dates-in-a-specific-tag?Date1=2022-12-30&Date2=2023-01-01&TagName=calculus) - however, this requires remembering which tag was used there. (And it also requires going through a long list of deleted questions one by one.)

---

- You can find some tips about searching among deleted questions, for example, here: [Are there some tools to follow deletions on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28315) or [Are there some possibilities for users below 10k to see deleted posts of other users?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13328)
- Here is a link to a general FAQ about searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265) However, the tips given there are focused on searching among questions which haven't been deleted.