# I really want to see a post but it was deleted. What should I do?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I found a post on Mathematics Stack Exchange by approach$0$ which would be very helpful to me, however opening it I saw it was deleted.

From the title, I saw `[closed]` in the title and other stuff like`your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?` and I guess it was closed and then deleted because of lacking content.

From the interface of approach$0$, I can see part of the solution, but it is not enough. As I really want to see the full post content, what should I do, is there any method?

(On the other hand, why does approach$0$ have access to deleted posts...)

Comment: You can have a look whether some of the suggestions from here are useful to you: [Are there some possibilities for users below 10k to see deleted posts of other users?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13328) Concerning your question about a deleted post appearing in some search engine, the explanation is easy - the post wasn't deleted at the time when this post was indexed by Approach0.

Comment: BTW if you have the URL, you can check whether some other questions are linked there - if you say that this question can be useful for you, perhaps the same is true for the linked questions. For example, this question is deleted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1281999. But since I know that the question id is 
1281999, I can use the URL `https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1281999` to see [the list of all linked questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1281999).

Comment: It appears (but I am not sure) that you can see the question (mathematical problem) as well along with part of solution. In that case you may well ask the question (with relevant context) and hope to get some nice answers.

Comment: Thanks for using approach0. However, for your purpose, I would recommend you to first check https://web.archive.org/